# trouble with AjaxControlToolkit tabcontainer

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager

I'm trying to move   ajax  tabcontainer  from one location to another  using JS code  ...

```
         function hideShow(myObject) {

         if(myObject.src.indexOf("plus.gif")>-1)
         {
             $(myObject).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '100%'>" + $(myObject).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
             $(myObject).next().remove();
             myObject.src = "images/minus.png";
             return;
         }

         if (myObject.src.indexOf("minus.png") > -1) {
             $(myObject).after("<div style=\"display:none\">" + $(myObject).closest("tr").next().html()+ "</div>")
             $(myObject).closest("tr").next().remove();
             myObject.src = "images/plus.gif";
             return;
         }
     }
```

the code works fine but  after moving it  the tabcontainer  doesn't    response on  hover or   on tab click. Moving back to it's original location  it functions  as  intended

Does anybody have  some idea what's wrong with it?